# Chrome: custom zoom level for apps

Tags: google-chrome, zooming, google-chrome-app

I have a custom zoom level (125%) for chrome. However this setting does not apply for chrome apps and they stick to 100% zoom level.

Is there a way to customize the zoom level for apps? Preferably on a per app basis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's one for extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-setZoom. To my best knowledge, there's nothing related for apps. Maybe it's a good feature request to be filled in [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).